# How to create instances with strings in php

Tags: php, class, variables, instance

I have a class called the 'analyst' and he has many 'analysers'. The analysers go looking for certain patterns in a given input.

For now, I create the instances of the 'analysers' in the constructor function of the anaylser like this:

```
<?php

class analyser {

protected $analysers = array();

public function __construct() {
    $analyser1 = new Analyser1();
    $this->analysers[] = $analyser1;
    $analyser2 = new Analyser1();
    $this->analysers[] = $analyser2;
    ...
}
```

This works for a limited amount of analysers but I want to create an array ('analyser1', 'analyser2', ...) that will be used in a loop to create all the needed instances. Is this possible or do I need to create every instance manually?

```
public function __construct() {
    foreach ($names as $analyser){
    $instance = new $analyser();
    $this->analysers[] = $instance;
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: yes I tried it and it gave me errors about not existing classes

Comment: Well, sounds like the next step should be to examine the error messages and find out why it thinks the classes do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

This should be straightforward - furthermore you could use nested associative array data to add some initial properties to each object, for example, you might want to give each object a name property:

```
<?php

class Analyser1
{
    protected $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$analyserData = [
  ['name' => 'analyser1'],
  ['name' => 'analyser2'],
  ['name' => 'analyser3'],
];

$analysers = [];

foreach ($analyserData as $data) {
  $obj = new Analyser1();
  $name = $data['name'];
  $obj->setName($name);
  $analysers[$name] = $obj;
  echo 'created ' . $obj->getName() . PHP_EOL;
}

print_r($analysers);
```

Yields:

```
created analyser1
created analyser2
created analyser3
Array
(
    [analyser1] => Analyser1 Object
        (
            [name:protected] => analyser1
        )

    [analyser2] => Analyser1 Object
        (
            [name:protected] => analyser2
        )

    [analyser3] => Analyser1 Object
        (
            [name:protected] => analyser3
        )

)
```

Example here: https://eval.in/133225

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple code:

```
public function __construct() {
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
        // if you want associative array, you should use this part
        $key = 'analyser' . $i;
        $this->analysers[$key] = new Analyser1();
    }
}
```

And it would create 10 instances of class Analyser1 in array $this->analysers